# Python3 knwowing if a disconnected client has reconnected

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am currently working on a test application involving a server and several client. The communication is achieved through the use of the TCP/IP protocol.
The server has several slots available. When a client connects, this one is affected to a slot. Is there a reliable way to identify if a disconnected client has reconnected?

I would like to reassign the disconnected client to its previous slot.

I do not really ask for code, but just clues that could help me to solve this problem.

Thanks for your answers.

### Edit

Working with MAC addresses should do it, login/pass, or pass-phrases.

Comment: A TCP client is uniquely identified by its source IP address and port, unless there are NAT devices.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I know but our teacher does not want us to use the IP of a client.

Answer (score 0):

Working with MAC addresses should do it, login/pass, or pass-phrases. – Papipone